# how to change UItableview's height and width in iPhone

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to change table's height and width. I used the below code:

```
tbl.frame=CGRectMake(0, 10, 50, 200);
```

on the `viewDidLoad` method, but it don't make any effect on table's height and width.

Comment: Maybe post some more code.

Comment: If you are going to adjust the frame by code, make sure that you have disabled the autoresizing in xib.

Comment: This is missing information. We need to know how you're loading the views (XIB/programmatically)? Are you using a normal `UIViewController`?

Comment: There must be some problem with your IBOutlate as In my demo it work well with viewDidLoad method and code `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 460.f);` here tableView is ivar declared as `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;` in .h file and synthesized in .m file using `@synthesize tableView = _tableView;`

Answer (score -1):

Use it in `viewWillAppear` method

```
tableSettings.frame = CGRectMake(17, 35, 288, 385);
```

Hope it will work.
Always do things like that in `viewWillAppear`.
because on loadTime its not effect.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using UITableViewController it wont take any effect but in case if you use UITableView you can try this code and along try using reload of tableview

```
tbl.frame=CGRectMake(0, 10, 50, 200); 
[tbl reloadData];
```

Comment: Thank u Vishnu Prasanth.. I have used UITableView only.. it won't make any change

Comment: @Balamurugan Just for clarification.. Have you connected the tableview outlet to file owner in xib?

Answer (score -2):

You can use this method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        return 50;
}
```

Comment: This affects the height of the cells, not the height of the table view.

Comment: Yes...Sorry,I thought he is asking about cell, Actually size of table u can easily increase or decrease